# Angular HttpClient.get always returns 404 Not found when calling Spotify webAPI

Tags: angular, rest, spotify

I tried many of the different Spotify webAPI and it always returns 404 not found. Here we are going to focus on the [api](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-list-of-current-users-playlists) to get current user playlists. I tried the api on postman and it returen the data in the same shape as described in the documentation. However, when I use the api in angular it always returns 404 Not Found.

[image: error message]

`library.service.ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LibraryService {
  private playlistsUrl = `${environment.apiUrl}me/playlists`;  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) { }

  getPlaylists(): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`)
    return this.http.get(this.playlistsUrl, {headers, withCredentials: true})
    .pipe(
      tap(_=>{console.log('fetched playlists');}),
      catchError(this.handleError('getPlaylists',[]))
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/JL978/spotify-clone-server) is the Repo I used to Handle the OAuth configurations. Can you please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `HttpHeaders` instance is **immutable**, so your changes are not being tracked, meaning that the token is not being sent to the Spotify API, hence the error.

Replace the line,

```
headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`)
```

with the following line,

```
headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`)
```

Comment: That is one problem and I’m really embarrassed of that mistake, but still the error persists. I also want to add that when I call the api without sending the token in postman it gives me error 401 the access token expired.

Comment: It happened to many of us, so don't worry about that. I don't see anything else wrong with your code. How are you getting the `access_token`? Are you sure that the OAuth configuration is correct? The endpoint that you are using require the `playlist-read-private` scope, are you sure that you set that up? In case of doubt, update your question to show us the OAuth configuration code.

Comment: I believe I handled the OAuth correctly because I used the token that is saved to the local storage to get the user playlist and it worked perfectly. The problem is I can't figure out how to do this in Angular because it seems like the endpoint doesn't even exist. However, if you are still curious I added the repo I used to handle the OAuth configuration to the main post.

Comment: Assuming your token is valid, I don't see anything wrong. I just tried it, and it worked fine on my end with similar code but `withCredentials` unset (or false), have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it :(

Comment: I will give you more ideas, for you to inspect, but again, your code is correct you are already doing it the correct way "in Angular".
Did you try a different endpoint?
Are you using an Angular `HttpInterceptor` that could be tempering the request?
Are you using a Service Worker that could be tempering the request?
Do you have a proxy configured in your browser?